# How to call it on my main.java (android)

Tags: java, android

```
public boolean updateCredential(Credentials credentials){
    boolean isSuccessful = true;
    SQLiteDatabase db=null;
    String whereStatement = Constants.LOGIN_ITEM + "=";
    String[] bindValues = new String[] {credentials.getLoginItem().trim()};
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    try{
        db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME, values, whereStatement, bindValues);
        db.close();
        IsSuccessful=true;
    }finally{
        db.close();
    }
    return isSuccessful;
}
```

for example i have an `addcredential()` method I call it like this in my form

```
public void addRecord(View v){
    credentials.setLoginItem(loginItemText.getText().toString());
    Db=new Passworkeeper(this); 
    if(db.addCredential(credentials)){
        loginItemText.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Record added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


public boolean addCredential(Credentials credential){
    boolean isSuccessful= false;
    SQLiteDatabase = null;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Constants.LOGIN_ITEM, credentials.getLoginItem().trim());

    Try{
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Db.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME,null, values);
        Db.close();

        isSuccessful =true;
    }finally{
        Db.close();
    }
        Return isSuccessful;
    }
}
```

Comment: andoid main is UI thread.
so use thread or post/postDelayed method of Handler.
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 5000);

Comment: this code is present on which class?

Comment: I dont know how to to call my update method in my form.java . My add and delete is already functioning

Comment: @sankyjain help me please

Comment: First of all your content value is empty add data you want to update.                  eg values.put("column_name",valueformCredentials);

Comment: @sankyjain cintent ? or intent ?

Comment: whatever data you want to update. Add it in values. Also can you add Credentials code

Comment: @sankyjain i already edit my post where in i included my addCredential method

Comment: So you want to update the credential you already added. In that case you need a unique identifier. Your primary key in database. What is your primary case in database

Comment: @sankyjain my unique identifier is LOGIN_ITEM .

Comment: Cause i have 2 EditText the username and password . username: a password: a . if i click add then it'll return a toast message that it is successfully added then if i have this view button that if i clicked it the username :a and password :a will appear on my EditText then if i change  my username:a to b then it is suppose to username:b and password:a vice versa . Thats is what im trying to do but i cant

Comment: Still not working :((

Answer (score 0):

Call using below method

```
public void updateRecord(View v){
    credentials.setLoginItem(loginItemText.getText().toString());
    if(db.updateCredential(credentials))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Record updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //show your toast
    }
    else
    {
        // updation failed
    }
}
```

Comment: So how should i call to my main.java